# residual vs fitted graph in R

Tags: r, time-series, lm

I want to plot residual vs fitted plot in R to show linearity of my data. I am using tslm() function. This is what I did.

```
 > plot(ts_model)
 Error in `[.default`(X, , piv, drop = FALSE) : 
 incorrect number of dimensions
```

I am unable to use plot() function. I tried another way to plot the residual vs fitted pot.

```
> #Get list of residuals
> res <- resid(ts_model)
> 
> #Linearity
> plot(fitted(ts_model),res)
> abline(0,0)
```

However, the red line is not showing. I want to include the red line to show the linearity.

[image: residual vs fitted plot using lm fucntion]

I want something like the above. This plot is using lm function but I want to plot this using tslm() fucntion.

[image: residuals vs fitted plot using tslm() function]
[image: dput(ts_model)]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(ts_model)`?

Comment: I actually included part of it because the output is too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of `plot.lm()`, the red line of the `plot.lm()` function is obtained when parameter `add.smooth=TRUE`. In turn, this parameter uses `panel.smooth()` to generate a smoothed curve that fits the plotted points. Finally, the documentation of `panel.smooth()` tells us that the function responsible for doing the smooth fit is `lowess()`.

Therefore, a line that plots the result of the call to `lowess()` should suffice to generate the red line that you are after. The following code illustrates (showcased with the sample data given in `help(tslm)` of the `forecast` package):

```
# Make generated plot reproducible
set.seed(1313)

# Generate the sample data
y <- ts(rnorm(120,0,3) + 1:120 + 20*sin(2*pi*(1:120)/12), frequency=12)

# Fit the tslm model
fit <- tslm(y ~ trend + season)

# Plot the residuals vs. fitted graph
# (note the use of as.numeric(), o.w. the points are connected by lines)
plot(as.numeric(fitted(fit)), as.numeric(residuals(fit)), type="p")

# Add a smooth trend line calling lowess(), as used by the plot.lm() function
lines(lowess(fitted(fit), residuals(fit)), col="red")
```

This is the resulting plot:

[image]